# Can't create tags, branches, or trunk

Tags: svn

In my my SVN repository, I'm trying to create tags/branches/trunk.

```
SVN1:/SVN/repo/android$ svnadmin create tempo
SVN1:/SVN/repo/android/tempo$ svn mkdir trunk
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

I can't get rid of this error. I can create a folder by doing `mkdir trunk`, but is this the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `svn mkdir` command can create a directory without a checkout, using the full URL form:

```
svn mkdir file:///SVN/repo/android/tempo/trunk -m "create trunk directory"
```

Note that you should not do things like directly create directories or files in your repository directory. The contents of the repository are managed by Subversion itself and should be considered off limits. Creating files or directories in there will not make those available through Subversion.

Comment: I tried that..gave me this error:
`svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found`

Comment: Okay, so use `-m` if you don't have an editor set up. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: and if I add a log message, `svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///SVN/repo/android'
`

Comment: Hm, not sure about that exactly. It's been a long time since I've actually set up a new Subversion repository. Are you running that command from the same machine that the repository exists on?

Comment: Yep, I'm SSH'ed into it using putty

Comment: Oh, sorry I see you've got an extra `tempo` directory in there. Try: `svn mkdir file:///SVN/repo/android/tempo/trunk -m "..."`